# What is wrong with my JavaScript? Function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get it so that when I click on a box, it'l turn black.

```js
function colorize() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('boardpic').innerHTML.src = "images/black.png";
}
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #87e0fd;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 74%, #05abe0 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 74%,#05abe0 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 74%,#05abe0 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0',GradientType=0 );
}

#title{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 96px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.boardpic{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

#container{
  display: flex;
}

#board{
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#colorpicker{
  font-size: 0;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 256px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Drawify | 0.0.1
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="title">
      Drawify
    </h1>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="board">
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
          <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="colorpicker">
      <div class="colorpickerline">
        <img src="images/red.png" />
        <img src="images/orange.png" />
        <img src="images/yellow.png" />
        <img src="images/green.png" />
        <img src="images/blue.png" />
        <img src="images/purple.png" />
        <img src="images/white.png" />
        <img src="images/black.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="code.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I click, the box doesn't change

I was pretty sure I was setting it up all right, but I guess not. So yeah, I am quite new to coding, so please explain with simple terms. :)

Comment: Why not set the background color to black/white instead of using images?

Comment: If you wanna set `src` of `img` tag you don`t need innerHTML. document.getElementsByClassName('boardpic').src = "images/black.png"

Comment: @Artin please post answers as answers not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Write your function like this:

```
function colorize(element) {
  element.src = "images/black.png";
}
```

and then as onclick event add this:

```
<img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize(this)" />
```

to each img element you want to change on click.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` as argument or use `event.target` to get clicked element!

`getElementsByClassName` returns array like collection hence you can not apply DOM methods directly on it, iteration of collection will be needed.

`innerHTML.src` is invalid syntax too, `innerHTML` returns `String`!

```js
function colorize(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.target.src = "images/black.png";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #87e0fd;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 74%, #05abe0 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 74%, #05abe0 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 74%, #05abe0 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0', GradientType=0);
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 96px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.boardpic {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
}

#board {
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#colorpicker {
  font-size: 0;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 256px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Drawify | 0.0.1
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">
    Drawify
  </h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="board">
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
        <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" onclick="colorize()" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="colorpicker">
    <div class="colorpickerline">
      <img src="images/red.png" />
      <img src="images/orange.png" />
      <img src="images/yellow.png" />
      <img src="images/green.png" />
      <img src="images/blue.png" />
      <img src="images/purple.png" />
      <img src="images/white.png" />
      <img src="images/black.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="code.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding a function to each element inside the DOM isn't effective and looks messy. I would suggest you to catch every element with `boardpic` class and just bind event listener which changes the `src` attribute of clicked element.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('boardpic');
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.src = 'https://placehold.it/350x150';
}));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #87e0fd;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 74%, #05abe0 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 74%, #05abe0 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 74%, #05abe0 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0', GradientType=0);
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 96px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.boardpic {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
}

#board {
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#colorpicker {
  font-size: 0;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 256px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">
  Drawify
</h1>
<div id="container">
  <div id="board">
    <div class="line">
      <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" />
      <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" />
      <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" />
      <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" />
      <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" />
      <img class="boardpic" src="images/white.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```